# Contrast clauses

Tags: grammar

Are these sentences correct?
 a) Our teacher didn't arrive late, in spite of the traffic being terrible.
Answer:  Our teacher didn't arrive late, in spite of the (terrible) traffic.

b) They have a car but they rarely use it, though.
 Isn't the use of *but* and *though* in the same sentence incorrect? 
Answer: They have a car, they rarely use it, though.
Thank you

Comment: Some of the tens of thousands of written instances of [*but it is though*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22but+it+is+though%22) will be "false matches" (for example, *But it is, though uncommon, far from unknown*). But enough of them *will* match the context here to establish that the "tautologous" usage has significant currency. So far as I'm concerned, there are some contexts where it's unquestionably ***acceptable*** (though never ***necessary***). But since there are other contexts where it's at least "questionable", it's probably best avoided by learners.

Comment: I don't know about your corrections, but what I know is that there is **no** need for a comma before _in spite of_, and there **has** to be a comma before _but_ in your second sentence.

Comment: @TasneemZh Removing the comma from the first sentence would completely alter its meaning: *She didn't arrive late in spite of the traffic being bad. Rather, she arrived late in spite of limping.* It's exactly the same as how *I didn't run because I was afraid* (*rather, I ran because I wanted exercise*) means something completely different from *I didn't run, because I was afraid* (*my fear caused me to run*).

Comment: @JasonBassford - I made sure of my point before posting it. But now that you have mentioned that, and I find it very reasonable indeed, I have noticed that all the [usages](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/in-spite-of-and-despite) of it without a comma was in affirmative form.

Comment: @TasneemZh Quite so. The distinction is only relevant with negative statements.